# Peculiar input current

Tags: input

[image]

[image]

[image]
http://www.cheemi-tech.com/product-current-transformers-CMPT107.html

Voltage between **B** & **C** is 119V which is equal to 1.19mA but input current between **A** & **B** is 14mA. Why is it so?

Edit: In the common perforated board, unused parts are blurred

**Edit 2**: *Let me assemble the circuit in another board and shall post the details*. 05june18

Comment: It can't be so. Unless you measure some momentary values of AC.

Comment: Check the battery on your meter.

Comment: @Andy: Fresh batteries are replaced, same result.

Comment: What is the scale of your current setting on your meter? If it's something like 1 A or 0.1 A you're just seeing the difficulties of converting low currents to voltages.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast: Its Fluke 106 with Autorange

Comment: Then you are likely having some rogue impedance between B and AC neutral that is taking most of the 14 mA - maybe a capacitor?

Comment: @Andy: Only those in the schematic are there.

Comment: Is this a simulation you are running or a real piece of hardware?

Comment: @Andy: In perforated common board

Comment: Post a picture is my recommendation.

Comment: How do you measure the current?\

Comment: @Eugene Sh: (Ref: Perforated board image) Between the open end of 100k and the black wire on the right side (live)

Comment: Check the resistor value once. If it is 10k, it looks possible to see what you are observing.

Comment: @Umar: Both are 100K, checked

Comment: Those are non-trivial currents. Try with another meter. Has anyone been fiddling around inside of yours, to repair and possibly forget the AC shield material or replace a resistor? You did move the red probe  to the mA jack, right?

Answer (score 1):

This is a meter error. If you look at [the data sheet](http://www.fluke.com/fluke/inen/digital-multimeters/compact-multimeters/fluke-106.htm?pid=77005) you'll see that the accuracy for AC current is 1.5% + 3 counts. However, if you look at the bottom of the page, you'll see that this is only specified over the range of 1% to 100% of the span. The smallest range in AC current is 4 amps, so any current less than 40 mA has no accuracy spec at all, and you simply can't trust it. 1.19 mA is less than 3% of 40 mA.

Don't believe your meter when you are misusing it.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

The section of the Fluke 106 datasheet mentioned by the user *WhatRoughBeast* is added for anyone who is interested. Thanks for all those who involved to find a solution.